# How can I access the edit history of a post?

Tags: support, editing

This must be somewhere in the help system, but I fail to find it with SE search which is not very good!  So, how do I see the edit history?

Comment: Do you just mean how to get a search to include previous versions of posts?

Comment: Yes. Somebody edited my post and I want to see what was changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the edit date shown, centered, immediately beneath the post:

[image: Screen shot]

This works everywhere else on SE wherever you have edit privileges.

Comment: I think it works independent of the edit privileges. Edit history is accessible to everybody.